# clone/copy to a new repo revisions 1 through n (i.e., up through a specified revision, but not to the current revision)

Tags: git, version-control

Consider the following repository:

[image: Image representing repository]

You can see we have 7 revisions (counting C0, the initial repo state). Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: we want to copy the repository, but only including revisions C0 through C3.

Conceptually, this feels to me like a git [clone](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) operation, but restricted to only the first 4 revisions. We want a new repository that retains history information on commits C0, C1, C2, and C3, but excludes everything after that.

I initially thought git clone with the "depth" parameter would work, but that allows you to start at the most recent revision and work backwards, correct? What I want to do is start at the oldest revision and work forward 3 revisions.

So, then I thought it might be possible to use git clone with [revision selection](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) for a range of commits. I tried a few different range selections, including `git clone {url} c0...c3`. But git simply interprets the range as a target folder, can creates a folder named `c0...c3` and places the repository clone in that folder.

Is it possible to copy a respository, and only grab revisions 0 through *n*? In my case, there are no branches to deal with, it's a single straight-line repo.

We're going to create a new product starting off the repo code at C3. It will never be merged back into the source project, as it's going to wind up completely diverging. If there is any code sharing between the two projects, it will be "offline" as far as git is concerned.

I understand we could branch off C3, but we very much want to keep the repos separate. Having said that, maybe branching is a part of the solution in creating a clean repo? Branch, clone the branch, then delete everything that is not either in the branch of an ancestor? But I'm not sure if we can or how to accomplish the deletion.

Background: an intellectual property dispute. We know that everything C3 and prior is "clean" IP, and there's question about the ownership of C4 and forward. We want to leave the current project as it is (and let the various parties dispute about it) and then move forward from a known "clean" commit. If we simply branched and kept working in the same repo, that's a little "too close for comfort" to the IP dispute. Everything we can do to separate ourselves from C4 and forward is good for us.

Comment: Don't do any of the above. Just reset your branch to C3, and get on with life. Git will eventually garbage-collect any unreachable commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a new branch from any specific commit.

```
git checkout -b new_branch <sha-of-C3>
```

So now, this `new_branch` is completely clean.

Creating a new repo out of it is simple - Just create a fresh repo on github (say `https://github.com/Josh/newrepo`), and add this repo as a remote in your existing repo as below:

```
git remote add newrepo https://github.com/Josh/newrepo
```

And now, push the `new_branch` on this `new_repo`

```
git push newrepo new_branch:master
```

This will create a branch `master` on `newrepo`, which will be same as the `new_branch`. 
Once you've verified all is well, you can delete your existing repo and start with a fresh clone of `newrepo`.

Comment: Sounds like it should work exactly as I need, so I upvoted. I've been diverted to another task at the moment but will try this ASAP, and then accept this answer or report if I encounter an issue. Thank you!

Comment: It did. Sorry it took me a few days to try this out and get back to you. Accepted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: One question though. In order to push to the new repository, I had to use `git init --bare`, otherwise I got "refusing to updated checked out branch." Is initializing a bare repository the right solution to this error? I got that from [here](http://qatechnotes.blogspot.com/2011/06/git-refusing-to-update-checked-out.html).